# regular expression to extract the user agent and browser from the text file

Tags: php, regex

- - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0

    - "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
      http://www.google.com/m?q=kuhas&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new    Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/27.1382; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10

Comment: Please format the question and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[\s-]+(?\[.*\])[\s"]+(?\w+)\s+(?[^\s]+)\s+(?[^\s]+)[\s"]+(?\d+)\s+(?\d+)([ -]+(?[.*)]))?/m';
 $str = '115.241.154.148    -   -   [31/Mar/2012:18:09:53   +0530]  GET / HTTP/1.1  200 1131    -   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)
117.199.7.144   -   -   [31/Mar/2012:19:32:37   +0530]  GET / HTTP/1.1  304 -   -   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
66.249.69.138   -   -   [31/Mar/2012:19:35:31   +0530]  GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1    404 613 -   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
66.249.69.138   -   -   [31/Mar/2012:19:35:31   +0530]  GET /kuhsonline/main/head.php HTTP/1.1  200 1157    -   "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
180.76.5.182    -   -   [31/Mar/2012:19:38:21   +0530]  GET / HTTP/1.1  200 1131    -   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($output);
 ?>